# Where should I ask this question?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Basically, where can I post such question?

> If I'm connected to a Minecraft server on computer A, then can I connect to the same server on computer B without the server noticing me disconnecting from computer A and reconnecting on computer B?
>
> Back in 2020 I think there was an exploit, which allowed bad actors to get anyone's session ID  and join the server that they were playing on, with the game kicking the legit player and letting the hacker join. But now, when I try to connect to a server that I'm connected to on computer A with computer B, I get such message:
>
> [image: permissions]
>
> **EDIT:** I'm trying to join 2b2t.org on Minecraft version 1.12.2 using impact cheats.

I tried posting it on Arqade, but they said that it's not about gaming; I tried posting it on Stack Overflow, but they said that it's not about software development.

Any suggestions on where to ask?

Comment: Questions asking for advise how to hack or exploit things should not be asked on Stack Exchange. I'm sure there are enough forums for black hat hackers.

Comment: And questions should be self-contained, i.e. not rely on a link to a website, even if it's another one in the network.

Comment: @ShadowTheKidWizard But I'm not an black hat hacker! I'm just trying to wait out the queue on my home server and then join on my desktop pc!

Comment: @Glorfindel Ok, I will try to self-contain it when I will ne home.

Comment: the issue with arquade seems like its cheating related, or trying to get around an intentional restriction

Comment: @BlayUng well, hacker might be extreme, but like Journeyman said, it is kind of cheating, which is also something not received well on SE.

Comment: Also, on a side note, your usage of symbol of hate as avatar does not help your cause.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well - I looked up [the server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2b2t) you wanted to play and well, they have a fairly ... interesting Wikipedia page:

> In response to the inundated server and hardware, a queue to enter the server was added. Before then, the server would have about ten players online at the same time. However, at the influx peak, the server have over a thousands of players waiting in queue.[14] The queue gave earlier 2b2t players priority over newer players,[3] although this feature was removed after a year.[15] The regular queue moves slowly and can contain over a thousand players.[2] Waiting in the queue has been described as an onerous task. Players can pay $20 to access a separate "priority" queue for one month.[3]

Arqade (Gaming.SE) is really meant for questions about playing a game. In this case you're trying to work around what's essentially server rate limiting due to a series of... interesting social issues on the server. I almost feel like a more 'general' question about 'moving' a program session between systems transparently might work but this feels like an issue with layers (2b2t's culture, their rate limiting, trying to move sessions between clients) that goes beyond any specific problem domain.

I don't really feel like any site here's a great fit - I don't think it'd do well as a generic computing question on Super User, it isn't about playing a game, so not Arqade, and wouldn't fit on Stack Overflow cause it isn't a programming question.